# How remove '$' ' " ' from (["$82,549.37","$3,239.51","$39.98","$17,958.95"])

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, string

```
var topGls = gls.sort(function(a, b) { return a - b; });
var json = JSON.stringify(topGls);
console.log(json);
```

This code provides a string which is starting with $ value and " , need to remove the same characters.

Comment: it's an array. loop on it and do some string search/replace.

Comment: do you want an array or a string returned?

Comment: If you found any of these answers helpful, you should upvote them. If one solved your issue, you should mark it as correct.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want a string returned with those values all mashed together, try

```
json.replace(/\$|"/g, "");
//"[82,549.37,3,239.51,39.98,17,958.95]"
```

If you would like an array of the strings, try:

```
json.split('","').map(function(num){ 
   return num.replace(/\$|\]|\[|"/g, "")
});

//["82,549.37", "3,239.51", "39.98", "17,958.95"]
```

Remove the commas too and add a `parseFloat` to get the numbers in a perhaps more useful format

```
json.split('","').map(function(num){ 
   return parseFloat(num.replace(/\$|\]|\[|"|\,/g, ""))
});
//[82549.37, 3239.51, 39.98, 17958.95]
```

Answer (score 2):

Use this:

```
var json = '["$82,549.37","$3,239.51","$39.98","$17,958.95"]';
json = json.split('"').join('').split('$').join('');
```

Result:

```
[82,549.37,3,239.51,39.98,17,958.95]
```

Comment: result is `"[82,549.37,3,239.51,39.98,17,958.95]"`

Answer (score 1):

`arr=["$82,549.37","$3,239.51","$39.98","$17,958.95"]
    var str=arr.join(',')
    str=str.replace('$','')
    arr = str.split(',')`

Bear in mind this only works because you have what looks like numbers. If they were strings it may be a problem because of the join on commas.